# QT_NO_EXCEPTIONS как отключить

Tags: qt, исключения

QVector написан таким образом, что выделенная память проверяется с помощью макроса `Q_CHECK_PTR`. В моей программе при неудачном аллоцировании `Q_CHECK_PTR` вызывает `qFatal`, который завершает программу. Меня это поведение не устраивает, я хочу получать исключение. В исходном коде `Q_CHECK_PTR` выглядит так:

```
    #ifdef QT_NO_EXCEPTIONS
768 #  if defined(QT_NO_DEBUG) && !defined(QT_FORCE_ASSERTS)
769 #    define Q_CHECK_PTR(p) qt_noop()
770 #  else
771 #    define Q_CHECK_PTR(p) do {if(!(p))qt_check_pointer(__FILE__,__LINE__);} while (0)
772 #  endif
773 #else
774 #  define Q_CHECK_PTR(p) do { if (!(p)) qBadAlloc(); } while (0)
775 #endif
```

Соответственно можно получить нужное мне поведение, если не дефайнить `QT_NO_EXCEPTION`. Как отключить `QT_NO_EXCEPTION` ?

Comment: можно взять и определить свой Q_CHECK_PTR, но это будет забивания гвоздей коллайдерами

Comment: @KoVadim , погуглив немного интенсивнее, обнаружил, что, видимо нужно пересобирать qt с флагом -exceptions. Но, честно говоря, мне пока некогда разбираться с тем как это делать. Не могли бы вы привести минимальный пример реализации вашего способа?

Comment: я подумал  и наверное нужно будет пересобирать Qt и в моем случае. Но я думаю, что Вы пытаетесь пофиксить костылем последствия вместо того, что бы исправить саму проблему.

Comment: @KoVadim, что вы имеете в виду? есть что-то плохое в желании получать исключение?)

Comment: нет ничего плохого в исключениях. Просто сам Qt изначально построен так, что бы не было исключений.

Comment: @KoVadim однако же вариант Q_CHECK_PTR с пробросом bad_alloc был прописан разработчиками...

Answer (score 0):

Это рабочий кусок, Qt5.7.1 VS2015 x86:

```
try {
    QVector<double>  a;
    a.resize(0x7FFFFFFF);
} catch (const std::bad_alloc &) {
    qDebug() << "bad alloc";
}
```

Окно Output:

```
Exception thrown at 0x7743B802 in prog.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x00CC0550.
Exception thrown at 0x7743B802 in prog.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.
bad alloc
```

Документация http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/exceptionsafety.html#out-of-memory-handling

Comment: интересно, возможно дело в том, что версия под VS2015 x86... можете попробовать у себя тоже самое с mingw провернуть?

Comment: Да MinGW 5.3.0, тоже Qt5.7.1, сделал консольный проект и он ловит std::bad_alloc